# How to use the phrase "in terms of"?

Tags: usage

How do I use the phrase "in terms of"?

Can there be a clause after "of"?

For example, can I say "This is a great show worth watching in terms of how hard the actors have been working to prepare for it"?

Comment: It's grammatically valid, but a rather unlikely context in which to use *in terms of X*. Usually this expression means [*regarding/concerning X*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+terms+of), in contexts where ***X*** is a factor or perspective that you wouldn't necessarily have in mind, and where there are definitely *other* perspectives that you're explicitly excluding by focussing on ***X***. So *"This is a great show in terms of the actors' lively performances, but the narrative thread is often confusing"*, say.

Answer (score 3):

You may certainly use a clause which acts as an NP as the complement of *in terms of*. Here's the first Google hit on "in terms of how hard":

> One of the major concerns of theoretical computer science is the classification of problems in terms of how hard they are. - Gasarch, [*Bounded Queries in Recursion Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=jBii_BJGOlYC&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=%22in+terms+of+how+hard%22&source=bl&ots=LjnotDHNnJ&sig=Yl5zEQ2_A41i1ZqO_u0oo2ESdVY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=diSTU7b1F4ir8gHisoH4Bg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22in%20terms%20of%20how%20hard%22&f=false)

But the particular clause you employ is problematic for me: how does the actors' difficulty in rehearsal factor as a term in a spectator’s enjoyment of the performance? (That, however, does not appear to be a problem which we can address here.)

FumbleFingers’ comment observes, cogently, that the problem may be the use of *in terms of* itself. Understood literally, *in terms of* announces the *terms* or categories you will use in speaking of the matter at hand; more generally, it is ordinarily used to head a phrase/clause which restricts the action of its main clause to a particular aspect or perspective which you are taking under  consideration. You might write

> This performance represents an extraordinary achievement in terms of how hard it was for the actors to prepare for it.

There you are judging the achievement *in terms of*—‘under the category of’—its difficulty, and excluding (for instance) the aesthetic effect and the emotional impact.

I don’t think that’s really what you mean; I think it more likely you intend something like

> This is a great show, all the more impressive if you know how hard the actors had to work to prepare for it.

Comment: I think I probably edited the question text *after* you'd read it and composed most of your answer (it's now *how hard the actors have been **working** to prepare*). Like you, I can't easily see *how the actors' difficulty in rehearsal might factor as a term in a spectator’s enjoyment of the performance* (how would the audience even *know* the rehearsals were "difficult"?). But once you switch from *great show* to *extraordinary achievement* it suddenly becomes perfectly natural to qualify that in terms of the demanding rehearsals.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks - I hadn't even noticed it had been edited. I've now excised what was irrelevant.